# What happened to ElasticsearchHealthIndicator?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot

I am looking at implementing health checks in Spring for Elastic Search.  All the online sources indicate that there should be a [ElasticsearchHealthIndicator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/ElasticsearchHealthIndicator.java) class out there but I cannot find it to use it.   The relevant Maven dependency is

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

Has this particular class been withdrawn from `spring-context-support`?  Has it been moved to another Maven package?

Answer (score 0):

The correct Maven dependency to get ElasticsearchHealthIndicator is the following.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Correct for Spring Boot 1.2.5 (the latest GA at the time of writing). Not hard-coding version like this allows to smoothly upgrade and avoid mixed versions in the project.

Comment: ... and get yourself into troubles when new bugs are introduced by the latest snapshots of 3rd-party libraries ;-) Good point, but out of context, though...

Comment: what are you talking about? You're never going to get snapshots with a Spring Boot GA release. No version does not mean the latest. No version means the one that is provided by dependency management.

Comment: Hmm.   Adding that did *not* fix the problem.   Maven cannot find that particular class even after adding that dependency.

Comment: What about using the artifact `spring-boot-starter-actuator` instead?